# Create object that contains array[] of other objects

Tags: c#, json

I want to receive a json object like this:

```
  "datasets": [{
                "label": "# of Votes",
                "data": [20, 10, 3],
                "backgroundColor": [
                         "#ccf9d6",
                         "#ccf9d6",
                         "#ccf9d6"
                               ],
                 "borderWidth": 1
           }]
```

but before Serialization I have to create object and I dont know how it should look in object in code behind. I have something like this but it's wrong.

```
datasets = new ChartDatasets[4]
                 {
                     label = "# of Votes",
                     data = new int[3] { 20, 10, 3 },
                     backgroundColor = new string[3] { "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6" },
                     borderWidth = 1
                 }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "it´s whrong"? Did you try to serialize this? What was the result? From my view it should produce the output given above. Anyway: you can omit the dimensions and even the type of your array when directly initializing it.: `data = new [] { 10, 20, 30 }`

Comment: Its wrong because It highlights the errors in the code.  `label, data, backgroundColor, borderWidth`  _..does not exist in the current context_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you create an array of type `ChartDatasets` which *may* hold up to four instances of that type, you don´t create an *instance* of this type. You´d need this instead:

```
datasets = new ChartDatasets[4] {
               new ChartDatasets {
                   label = "# of Votes",
                   data = new int[3] { 20, 10, 3 },
                   backgroundColor = new string[3] { "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6" },
                   borderWidth = 1
               }
           }
```

However you can also omit the dimension and even the type of your arrays as the compiler will try to infer the right types automatically:

```
datasets = new [] {
               new ChartDatasets {
                   label = "# of Votes",
                   data = new [] { 20, 10, 3 },
                   backgroundColor = new [] { "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6", "#ccf9d6" },
                   borderWidth = 1
               }
           }
```

As an aisde you should consider to name instances of your type in singular, unless they really represent some kind of a collection. In your case you have an array (which surely is a collection) of instances of type `CharDataset`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [neat website](http://json2csharp.com/) that translates JSON to nice C# code. Your question is tagged as C# so I am guessing that i what you want.

It outputs this for your code:

```
public class Dataset
{
    public string label { get; set; }
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
    public List<string> backgroundColor { get; set; }
    public int borderWidth { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Dataset> datasets { get; set; }
}
```

As far as creating an object that has an array of other objects, I'd recommend a the approach from the code above where you have a list of classes and each class has a number of objects